# QDirModel setNameFilters hides folders

Tags: qt, file, filter, directory, qdir

I want to have a `QDirModel` that contains both folders and files (so I am using `AllEntries`).

The problem is that when I am calling `setNameFilters()` on my `QDirModel`, I'll loose all the folders.
Is there any way that I can exclude folders from filtering?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `QFileSystemModel` instead `QDirModel`:

> The usage of QDirModel is not recommended anymore. The
>   QFileSystemModel class is a more performant alternative.

Qt documentation: [QDirModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdirmodel.html) and [QFileSystemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html)

For your question - look for combination of flags: `QDir::AllDirs | QDir::Files` in [setFilter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#setFilter)

Simple example, if you use `QDirModel`:

```
QTreeView view;
QStringList filters;
filters << "*.txt";
QDirModel* dirModel = new QDirModel(&view);
dirModel->setFilter(QDir::AllDirs | QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
dirModel->setNameFilters(filters);
view.setModel(dirModel);
view.show();
```

Simple example, if you use `QFileSystemModel`:

```
QTreeView view;
StringList filters;
filters << "*.txt";
QFileSystemModel* fileSystemModel = new QFileSystemModel(&view);
fileSystemModel->setRootPath("C:/");
fileSystemModel->setFilter(QDir::AllDirs | QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
fileSystemModel->setNameFilterDisables(false);
fileSystemModel->setNameFilters(filters);
view.setModel(fileSystemModel);
view.show();
```

Comment: thank you @Kirill Chernikov. But, the question remains.. How is possible to exclude folders from being filtered?

Comment: As you can see in documentation: "QDir::AllDirs - List all directories; i.e. don't apply the filters to directory names." When you wiil set filters for name, this filters will not apply for directories (folders), but only for files.